# Softbody to only deform on collision?

Tags: animation, physics, collision, soft-body

I have a softbody which should bounce and deform when hit, so I give it some weight painting at the points which should deform the most.

The problem is that, the softbody will deform a little immediately before it is even bit (because of the weight painting vertex group goal)

Is there a way to stop a weight painted vertex group goal from deforming the object, except for when it meets a collision?

Comment: Under Cache change start frame of simulation.

Comment: Unfortunately this is an issue with the mesh deforming rather than a timeline frame issue

Comment: Sure :) but your Q is how to prevent deforming object before collision. Setting start frame at collision frame will gives you this effect, yes it is workaround, but fastest one :) In general I would suggest to use Cloth sim (instead of SoftBody) with "Internal Springs" enabled.